# LED Strips - Data Noise Over Long Distance Between Controller and First Strip

Tags: noise, led-strip, data, ground-loop

[image: LED Strip Diagram 1]

Please refer to the above picture.

The black line is the ground wire and the green line is the wire carrying data.

First Question

In regards to data noise/interference, can the output ground wire of the power supply and controller be connected at the blue circled part instead of the purple circled part given that the distance between the controller and the first led strip is 11 meter?

Second Question

If the answer to the above is yes, does using coaxial cable for ONLY the data wire help in reducing interference? We are unable to use twisted pair for the ground and data wire and the ground is shared between the power and the data.

Third Question

[image: LED Strip Diagram 2]

Does it make a difference in terms of data noise/ground loop if the data and ground are wired as per diagram 2 instead of diagram 1?

Thank you.

EDIT:

[image: New Diagram]

Answer (score 1):

1. No.
2. No
3. No.

These are daisy chained data IN data OUT Reels with a limit of 10m for power and not  1 to many “Tree” With branch reels at  noisy different ground voltages for power and data return return due to high current voltage drops of hundreds of mV.

The data must be “snaked” or Daisy chained with alternating directions from one to the next for data.

The power must be distributed to limit the current in each reel such that the change in ground shift due to LED current does not affect the signal integrity.

I see you are going to keep asking about this and you will need to find an “Engineer” with experience to resolve this solution with a design then verify a scope and stray noise., so the  expert can achieve optimal signal integrity and no weird flashing lights over a 70m daisy chain bus.

These current loops degrade signal integrity between reels and may be prone to random LEDs flashing or not working.

Comment: So that means power connected in parallel while data should be connected in series (I have edited and attached a new diagram to reflect this). One question though, does having a separate data and ground wire for each run of strip solve the noise issue as well? Asking because i have a situation where the colour must be run in parallel instead of from A to B (left and right side of a hallway).

Comment: No if the power voltages drops from one end to their other that shifts your data ground too. So must be analyzed to see effects for LED power ground shift noise but now I see different lengths much shorter